# Spring boot Interface projection How to return desired JSON structure

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa, projection

I am using an Interface Projection

```
public interface Dashboard
{
    public int getProjectID();
    
    // Review table
    List<ReviewRs> getReviews();
    
    // StakeHolder table
    List<SteakHolderRs> getstakeHolders();
    
    interface ReviewRs
    { 
        int getReviewId();
        String getReviewsType();
    }
    
    interface SteakHolderRs
    {
        int getId();
        String getProjectResource();
    }
    
}
```

The above interface returns the below JSON structure

```
{
    "dashboards": [
        {
            "projectID": 211281,
            
            "reviews": [
                {
                    "reviewsType": "Assessment Review",
                    "reviewId": 396
                },
                {
                    "reviewsType": "HLSD Review",
                    "reviewId": 423
                }
            ],
            "stakeHolders": [
                {
                    "id": 468,
                    "projectResource": "Joseph"
                },
                {
                    "id": 644,
                    "projectResource": "Renji"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I want The JSON to look like this

```
{
    "dashboards": [
        {
            "projectID": 211281,
            
            "reviews":
                {
                    "reviewsType": "Assessment Review",
                    "reviewId": 396
                },
            "stakeHolders": [
                {
                    "id": 468,
                    "projectResource": "Joseph"
                },
                {
                    "id": 644,
                    "projectResource": "Renji"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "projectID": 211281,
            
            "reviews":
                {
                    "reviewsType": "HLSD Review",
                    "reviewId": 423
                },
            "stakeHolders": [
                {
                    "id": 468,
                    "projectResource": "Joseph"
                },
                {
                    "id": 644,
                    "projectResource": "Renji"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

The **reviews** object are no longer grouped together, but are separated based on reviewsType field

Repo interface

```
@Repository
public interface ProjectRepo extends JpaRepository<Project, Integer>
{   
    public List<Dashboard> findAllProjectedBy();
}
```

Project class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "project")
public class Project
{   
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "ProjectID")
    private int projectID;
    
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "h_project", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<Review> reviews;
    
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "l_project", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<StakeHolder> stakeHolders;
    
    //getters and setters removed for brevity
}
```

Review class (Omitting StakeHolder class because it looks the same)

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "review")
public class Review
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "reviewID")
    private int reviewId;
    
    @Column(name = "ReviewsType")
    private String reviewsType;
    
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    @JoinColumn(name = "projectId", insertable=false, updatable=false)
    private Project h_project;
    
    //getters and setters removed for brevity
}
```

How can I return the JSON structure I want using interface projections?

Comment: Your expected structure actually don't match with the entity structure, so you can restructure manually after fetching

Comment: Yes. How can I restructure to match the results I want? I keep trying different interface restructuring, but am unable to get the desired results.

Comment: I don't think it's possible directly in the interface, you need to fetch in interface and then restucture you data in class manually.

Comment: Thank you. Do you have recommendations for how to restructure the data inside the interface manually, or keywords for me to google to get me started?

Comment: Create a class for your expected structure(ex: `DashBoardResponse` ) and create a converter class for like `DashBoardResponse convert(Dashboard d, Review r)`. Then loop over `List<Dashboard>` then nested loop for `List<Review>` of each `Dashboard` and call convert to converter method to get `DashBoardResponse` and add in an arraylist.